# Can't access methods in sub class when using the super as the reference type

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a problem where I have some class say

```
 public class Foo {

   public Foo() {
    // Do stuff
   }

   public void generalMethod() {
      //to general stuff
   }

 }

 public class Bar extends Foo {

     public Bar() {
        //do stuff
     }

     public void uniqueMethod() {
        //do stuff
     }
 }


 public class Driver() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Foo test = new Bar();

       test.uniqueMethod(); //this causes an error
    }
 }
```

So i get an error which says, that the method `uniqueMethod()` is undefined for Foo, but when I change the assignment to `Bar test = new Bar();` the problem goes away. I dont understand as it should work with `Foo test = new Bar();`

Can someone suggest a reason for which why this error occurs?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why should it work with `Foo`? There is no such method in that class.

Comment: Because since Foo is a parent class should the JVM not look at the sub classes for the uniqueMethod() since it is not in the parent class (Foo)

Comment: JVM doesn't matter here. The compiler is at work and he only looks at the defined variable type. Polymorphy (what you mean here) happens during _runtime_, not _compile time_.

Comment: It works with the declared type, meaning the type you define right before the variable name, not the type which will be assigned to it at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the method is there at runtime, the compiler only sees that the object `test` of type `Foo` DOES NOT have the method uniqueMethod. Java works with virtual method, where the method that will be invoked is determined at `runtime`. So, again, the compiler does not see that this specific instance's type is a `Bar`. If you really need to invoke that method, you could a cast and invoke the method:

`((Bar)test).uniqueMethod();`

Now, to the compiler, you have the type `Bar`, and he can see all the methods that are available at `Bar` type

### Think like the compiler and JVM

### Example 1

`Foo test = new Bar();`

*So, I have one variable that is of type Foo. I MUST validate that all subsequent calls to members of this class are OK* - It will look for all members in `Foo` class, the compiler doesnt even look for the instance type.

In `runtime`, the JVM will know that we have a variable of type `Foo`, but with instance type `Bar`. The only difference here is that it, JVM, will look to the instance to make the [virtual calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453701/what-is-virtual-method-calling-in-java) to the methods.

### Example 2

`Bar test = new Bar();`

*So, I have one variable that is of type Bar. I MUST validate that all subsequent calls to members of this class are OK* - It will look for all members in `Foo` and 'Bar' classes, the compiler, again, doesnt even look for the instance type.

In `runtime`, the JVM will know that we have a variable of type `Bar`, and an instance of the same type:`Foo`. Now we again, have access to all the members defined in `Foo` and `Bar` classes.

Comment: thank you for sharing the syntax of `((Bar)test).uniqueMethod();`. I've known about being able to treat an object as it's subclass by casting it to a new variable with the declared subtype like `Bar actualBar = (Bar) test;`, because `(Bar) test.uniqueMethod()` wouldn't work. Who knew how useful an extra set of parentheses could be :)

Answer (score 2):

useing late binding you must have the same method in the super class "Fathor" , or it will not work !

this work with me

//

```
public  class foo {
public void print(){
System.out.println("Super,"+2);}
```

}

class bo extends foo {

```
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Sup,"+9);
        }
```

}

Test //

public abstract class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     foo t = new bo();
     t.print();
}
```

}
///

output

Sup,9

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the compiler does not know that `test` is of type `Bar`, it only knows the declared type of `Foo`.

```
public void test(Foo foo) {
        // error! this method can accept any variable of type foo, now imagine if you passed it 
        // another class that extends Foo but didnt have the uniqueMethod. This just wont work
        foo.uniqueMethod(); 
    }
```