# Is there a way to access the concrete class variable values from concrete methods of an abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an understanding of [variable hiding and method overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847300/java-method-overriding-and-variable-shadowing) and [virtual method calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453701/what-is-virtual-method-calling-in-java) in Java. 
My question is, why does variable hiding fail to take effect in inherited methods? Does it mean that we have to override the methods which access those variables in every child class?

**Abstract class**

```
public abstract class ClassA{

    protected int i = 0;

    public void printOurStuff(){
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public void printMyStuff(){
        System.out.println(this.i);
    }

    public void printSomeStuff(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

**Concrete class**

```
 public class ClassB extends ClassA{

     protected int i = 1;

     public static main(String[] args){
         ClassB b = new ClassB();
         b.printOurStuff();
         b.printMyStuff();
         b.printSomeStuff(b.i);
     }

 }
```

**Results**

0
0
1

**EDIT** - changed the access modifier of the field from private to protected and added method `printOurStuff`

Comment: It's not clear which result you want to change - the result of calling `printMyStuff` or the result of calling `printSomeStuff(b.i)`. But those are two entirely separate variables, and each variable is only accessible to code within the same class declaration, as they're both private variables.

Comment: No. It means you should avoid hiding fields. If `i` needs to be available in subclasses, make it protected, or add a protected getter method that you can call in subclasses.

Comment: @JBNizet changing the access modifier does not fix this anyway. However, I am asking for an explanation on why does this happen, not how to do this

Comment: It does if you stop hiding fields, i.e. if you remove the `i` field in ClassB and thus have a single `i`field.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the problem of my interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare private fields like

```
  private int i = 0;
```

that means that only this concrete class may access this variable. This field is not available to subclasses. If you want this field to be available for subclasses, you should make it `protected` instead:

```
  protected int i = 0;
```

To override the value of this field you can use a static block, f.e.:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    {
         i = 1;
    }
}
```

or assign a new value in the constructor:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
     public ClassB() {
         i = 1;
     }
}
```

As to your example, if you inspect `ClassB` object with a debugger, you'll find that you actually have two `i` fields: one for `ClassA` and one for `ClassB`.

**UPDATE:**

As to the case where `i` variable is `protected`:
Look carefully at your classes definition. 
You can not disagree that you *declare* `i` field two times: for `ClassA` and `ClassB`. JVM will respect this declaration and follow your instructions. If the field is `protected` or even `public`, you still have two fields. You can not just override them as you override methods. And when accessing a field like `i = ...` you're actually accessing the closest field to your scope. For `ClassB` it's its field `i`, not the field of its superclass `ClassA`.

Also, you can still access the field of the superclass as follows:

```
super.i = ...
```

`super` is the reference to the super class.

Comment: Setting access modifier to private was a mistake I did when posting the question. While adding a static block and assigning the variable in the constructor is totally acceptable as solutions to this problem, I am more concerned about knowing why does this happen. Is it because of the scope of the concrete methods in the abstract class are limited to that of the abstract class?

Comment: @KusalHettiarachchi no. It's because fields are not polymorphic. They can't be overridden. Only methods can be overridden. So, if a variable (`this` here) is of type ClassA, and you access the field `i` of this variable, then the compiler will resolve it statically to `ClassA.i`.

Comment: @KusalHettiarachchi, provided some explanation in the answer.

Comment: @JBNizet i dont have any problem with the `b.i` being resolved to the value of 1. I want to know why the method `printOurStuff` evaluates the value of i to the value set in ClassA

Comment: @PavelSmirnovyour, my question lies in method `printOutStuff`evaluating i to be 0, although it is called on an instance of ClassB.

Comment: And I answered to that: because, inside printOurStuff, the implicit variable `this` is of type `ClassA`, and thus `i` is statically resolved to the field `i` declared in `ClassA`. Fields are not polymorphic. They are resolved at compile time.

Comment: @KusalHettiarachchi, `printOutStuff` is declared inside `ClassA`. It does not even know about `ClassB`. The reference `i` in `System.out.println(i);` references `ClassA.i` field. This is the same as `System.out.println(this.i);` where `this` is the reference to `ClassA`.

Comment: @KusalHettiarachchi, just think about it this way: you do not override `i` field in `ClassB`, you do not override `printOutStuff` method. So why should it use an absolutely new variable `ClassB.i` instead of `ClassA.i`?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov so variable hiding does not work for concrete methods implemented in abstract methods unless we effectively override the methods in child classes?

Comment: Then this is why it is necessary to initialize the variable in the constructor or in a static block. Thank you @PavelSmirnov for the guidance

Comment: @KusalHettiarachchi, you do not actually have to initialize it in the constructor or in a static block, if you do not have name conflict. It's just the scope issue: two variables with the same name, so the compiler chooses the closest one accroding to the scope.