# How does the dispatch of extensions declared as members relate to receiver type in this example?

Tags: class, kotlin, inheritance

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473476) but I'm still confused. When looking at this [example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) in the docs...

```kotlin
open class Base { }

class Derived : Base() { }

open class BaseCaller {
    open fun Base.printFunctionInfo() {
        println("Base extension function in BaseCaller")
    }

    open fun Derived.printFunctionInfo() {
        println("Derived extension function in BaseCaller")
    }

    fun call(b: Base) {
        b.printFunctionInfo()   // call the extension function
    }
}

class DerivedCaller: BaseCaller() {
    override fun Base.printFunctionInfo() {
        println("Base extension function in DerivedCaller")
    }

    override fun Derived.printFunctionInfo() {
        println("Derived extension function in DerivedCaller")
    }
}

fun main() {
    BaseCaller().call(Base())   // "Base extension function in BaseCaller"
    DerivedCaller().call(Base())  // "Base extension function in DerivedCaller" - dispatch receiver is resolved virtually
    DerivedCaller().call(Derived())  // "Base extension function in DerivedCaller" - extension receiver is resolved statically
}
```

And regarding this quote

> An instance of a class in which the extension is declared is called a **dispatch receiver**, and an instance of the receiver type of the extension method is called an **extension receiver**.

I assume that only instances of Base() and Derived() can be extension receivers, because we only defined extensions for those two classes. And I assume that only instances of BaseCaller() and DerivedCaller() can be dispatch receivers, because we only declare extensions inside those classes.

My confusion stems from the two comments at the bottom of the example where it says "dispatch receiver is resolved virtually" and "extension receiver is resolved statically". Are they referring to DerivedCaller() in both cases? Is DerivedCaller() a dispatch receiver in one line and an extension receiver in the next? How can it be an extension receiver if we never declare any extensions for it? Or are they referring to Base() as the dispatch receiver and Derived() as the extension receiver? How can Base() be a dispatch receiver, if it never declares any extensions?

I know that call() always resolves statically to use an instance of Base, and I know the version of Base.printFunctionInfo() will depend on what object I call the call() method on (either BaseCaller() or DerivedCaller()), but I'm confused about what those comments are saying. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure where your confusion comes from. You understand it correctly: dispatch receivers are either `BaseCaller` and `DerivedCaller` and extension receivers are `Base` and `Derived`. In comments quoted by you they mean exactly the same thing: that `BaseCaller`/`DerivedCaller` is resolved virtually and `Base`/`Derived` is resolved statically. Why do you think they mean a different thing?

Comment: "Are they referring to DerivedCaller() in both cases?" No. And I think that answers all of your questions...?

Comment: "I know that call() always resolves statically to use an instance of Base" <--- this is the second comment's point. "and I know the version of Base.printFunctionInfo() will depend on what object I call the call() method on" <--- this is the first comment's point.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I think I understand now (especially after @Sweeper 's second comment, I hope you enjoy the donation - happy holidays!). I'll answer my own question, if I still get something wrong I'd appreciate any further correction. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally confused by these two comments from the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members)

1. "dispatch receiver is resolved virtually"
2. "extension receiver is resolved statically"

In the first comment, the "dispatch receiver" refers to the `DerivedCaller()` instance. It's virtual because they could've called the `call()` method on a `BaseCaller()` instance or a `DerivedCaller()` instance (but they ended up calling it on a `DerivedCaller()` instance). This first comment is concerned with which extension method to call, the one in `BaseCaller` or the one in `DerivedCaller`

In the second comment the "extension receiver" refers to the `Derived()` instance that gets passed into `call()`. This second comment is concerned with which member function get's called from inside the `DerivedCaller` class. The `Base.printFunctionInfo()` or the `Derived.printFunctionInfo()`. In this case the extension receiver is resolved statically, so instead of using `Derived()` it uses `Base()` instead because that's how my extension function is setup (and [extension functions are always resolved statically](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically)).

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to understand if we realize that `Base.printFunctionInfo()` and `Derived.printFunctionInfo()` are much different functions, only named the same. If we rename them, this example becomes obviously clear:

```kotlin
open class BaseCaller {
    open fun Base.printFunctionInfoForBase() {
        println("Base extension function in BaseCaller")
    }

    open fun Derived.printFunctionInfoForDerived() {
        println("Derived extension function in BaseCaller")
    }

    fun call(b: Base) {
        b.printFunctionInfoForBase()   // call the extension function
    }
}

class DerivedCaller: BaseCaller() {
    override fun Base.printFunctionInfoForBase() {
        println("Base extension function in DerivedCaller")
    }

    override fun Derived.printFunctionInfoForDerived() {
        println("Derived extension function in DerivedCaller")
    }
}
```

In `call()` we only have a `Base` object, so we can only invoke `printFunctionInfoForBase()`, but we can't invoke `printFunctionInfoForDerived()` there. Then, we clearly see that `printFunctionInfoForDerived()` is really never invoked anywhere in this code.

In other words, `Base.printFunctionInfo()` and `Derived.printFunctionInfo()` are two **overloads** of the function.  `DerivedCaller` provides **overrides** of `BaseCaller` functions.